# Class stringstream. Cant understand how lineStream works, its parameters;

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code, and I know how it works and what it does, however, not at all. I don't understand how these three lines work 
                        **std::stringstream lineStream(line);
            std::string cell;
            std::getline(lineStream, cell, ';')**
Especially lineStream one;
 I found them in google, but no sufficient explanation. Could you explain me please their behavior or share a good link please? Thanks in advance, have a nice day :)

```
    container *begin = new container;
    begin->beginBox = new box;
    container *last = NULL;

    std::ifstream  data(filename);
    std::string line;
    std::getline(data, line);

    for (container *i = begin; !data.eof() && std::getline(data, line);)
    {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        std::string cell;
        std::getline(lineStream, cell, ';');
        i->ID = atoi(cell.c_str());
        for (box *j = i->beginBox; std::getline(lineStream, cell, ';'); j->next = new box, j = j->next)
        {
            j->apples = atoi(cell.c_str());
            i->lastBox = j;
        }

        i->lastBox->next = NULL;
        i->nextCont = new container(), last = i, i = i->nextCont, i->beginBox = new box;
    }
    setAutoIncrement(begin->ID + 1);
    last->nextCont = NULL;
    return begin;
```

Comment: You don't need the `!data.eof()` in the outer loop condition, the `std::getline` call will return the stream object and it can be used in boolean expressions directly.

Comment: As for your problem, read about [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::stringstream lineStream(line);
```

This declares a variable called `lineStream` of type [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). It passes the `line` string to [its constructor (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream). The `std::stringstream` type wraps a string with a stream interface. It means you can treat it like `cout` and `cin`, using `<<` and `>>` to insert and extract things from the string. Here, `lineStream` is being created so you can later extract its contents using `std::getline`.

```
std::string cell;
```

This just declares an empty `std::string` called `cell`.

```
std::getline(lineStream, cell, ';');
```

The function [`std::getline` (1)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) takes a stream that it will extract a line from as its first argument. The second argument is a `std::string` that it will extract the line into. Without a third argument, the ending of a "line" is considered to be where we see a newline character. However, by passing a third argument, this code is making so that a line ends at `;`. So this call to `std::getline` will extract everything from the stream up until it finds a `;` character and puts that content into `cell`. The `;` character is then discarded.

---

This is all very similar to the above code:

```
std::ifstream  data(filename);
std::string line;
std::getline(data, line);
```

Here, the stream is a file stream instead of a string stream, and `std::getline` will extract everything up to a newline character because no third argument is given.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. Does it mean that stringstream lineStream is something very similar to usual string, but the difference is that stringstream allows to use >> and << ?

Comment: it is clear with getline and string, but not at all with streamstring

Comment: @user3336406 `getline` has to take a stream as its first argument. `line` is not a stream, so you can't pass that by itself. Instead, you can create a `std::stringstream` which provides a stream interface to whatever string you give it, then you can pass that to `getline`.

Comment: @user3336406 `std::stringstream` is not similar to a `std::string` - it's similar to other streams, like file streams, `std::cout` and `std::cin`, etc. The thing that makes `std::stringstream` useful is that it streams from a `std::string`.